# SpringBoot urlencodes plus sign in query parameters in an inconsistent manner

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple echo controller

```
@RestController
public class EchoController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/param", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    String echoParam(@RequestParam("p") String paramValue) {
        return paramValue;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/path-variable/{val}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    String echoPathVariable(@PathVariable("val") String val) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

One of its methods echoes the value of a parameter it was presented; the second does the same with a value provided via URI.

I have the following tests:

```
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

@Test
public void rawPlus_inQueryParam() {
    String value = "1+1";

    String response = getValueEchoedThroughQueryParam(value);

    assertThat(response, is(equalTo(value)));
}

@Test
public void urlencodedPlus_inQueryParam() {
    String value = "1%2B1";

    String response = getValueEchoedThroughQueryParam(value);

    assertThat(response, is(equalTo(value)));
}

private String getValueEchoedThroughQueryParam(String value) {
    return webTestClient.get()
            .uri(builder -> {
                return builder
                        .path("/param")
                        .queryParam("p", value)
                        .build();
            })
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
            .expectBody(String.class)
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();
}
```

Both tests just send a string via the query parameter, read the response and assert that the content was echoed correctly.

First test fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "1+1"
     but: was "1 1"
```

Second test passes.

Looks like in the second test, the `WebTestClient` url-encodes the value (actually, it just url-encodes the percent character), then the web-server url-decodes it, and everything is ok. But in the first test, the client does **not** url-encode the plus character, but the server **does** url-decode it, hence it gets a space character.

This looks like an inconsistency. I doubt I could do something stupid to cause it because everything works in the default mode; actually, the controller I show here is almost the only code the application has (Application class itself is default, I did not touch it after it was generated).

Just to compare: when passing the same data in URI, everything works correctly. The following tests pass:

```
@Test
public void rawPlus_inPathVariable() {
    String value = "1+1";

    String response = getValueEchoedThroughPathVariable(value);

    assertThat(response, is(equalTo(value)));
}

@Test
public void urlencodedPlus_inPathVariable() {
    String value = "1%2B1";

    String response = getValueEchoedThroughPathVariable(value);

    assertThat(response, is(equalTo(value)));
}

private String getValueEchoedThroughPathVariable(String value) {
    return webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/path-variable/" + value)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
            .expectBody(String.class)
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();
}
```

**The questions are**:

1. Is this a bug in Spring Boot (or one of the components it uses)?
2. If not, did I do something wrong?
3. And the practical question: how can you pass a query parameter value that contains plus character in tests written against `WebTestClient`? If I don't url-encode it manually, it gets url-decoded by the web-server; if I do, it gets url-encoded second time, so the server gets (after url-decoding) an url-decoded version.

Spring Boot version is `2.1.4.RELEASE` (the most recent at the moment of writing).

POM follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-plus-in-query-string</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-plus-in-query-string</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The project is available at GitHub: https://github.com/rpuch/springboot-plus-in-query-string

Just run the tests (`mvn clean test`).

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455594/spring-boot-prevent-decoding-for-requestparam

Comment: @javapedia.net it does not look like a duplicate. There, the OP wants to disable the decoding. Here, I want to understand why the encoding+decoding is inconsistent and know how to fix it: by fixing a bug in Tomcat, by fixing a bug in web-client, or doing something else.

Comment: This behaviour is the standard. Have you tried `"1%2B1"`?

Comment: @Bohemian yes I did. It is in the question :) `%` gets encoded, so we get double-encoded plus character in the request; web-server decodes it one time, and the controller gets `1%2B1` and not `1+1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21399)

> The key to understand this, is that different degrees of encoding are
>   applied to the URI template vs URI variables. In other words given:
>
> `http://example.com/a/{b}/c?q={q}&p={p}`
>
> The URI template is everything except for the URI variable
>   placeholders. However the code snippet you showed only builds a URI
>   literal without any variables, so the level encoding is the same, only
>   illegal characters, no matter which method is used.
>
> So it would also have to be something like:
>
> .queryParam("foo", "{foo}").buildAndExpand(foo)

Therefore the idea is to use something like:

```
builder
      .path("/param")
      .queryParam("p", "{value}")
      .build(value)
```

to get the query param encoded.

Comment: Thank you, Eugen! I've also added some details in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some details.

The snippet suggested by @Eugen Covaci actually works:

```
            .uri(builder -> {
                return builder
                        .path("/param")
                        .queryParam("p", "{value}")
                        .build(value);
            })
```

One thing that still remains strange is: why does it happen that writing (seemingly) the same code in a more verbose manner yields a different result? Two forms (pure literal and the one using URI variables) actually use different encoding levels for query parameters, and this looks like a violation of the Principle of least astonishment to me.

It looks like this is caused by legacy problems: earlier, there was a bug: `+` character was always encoded, although it should not be. Now, the authors fixed the bug, but it created an inconsistency: `.queryParam("p", "{value}").build(value)` is not the same as `.queryParam("p"), value).build()`.

Looks like one has to just know/remember this.

The full working method code is

```
private String getValueEchoedThroughQueryParam(String value) {
    return webTestClient.get()
            .uri(builder -> {
                return builder
                        .path("/param")
                        .queryParam("p", "{value}")
                        .build(value);
            })
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
            .expectBody(String.class)
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();
}
```

Comment: When using `build` it will do encoding, when not using `build` it assumes the value will be already encoded. In that case a `+` is the encoded value for a whitespace.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, I don't understand: how can you not use `build()` (any of 2)? Without it you have `UriBuilder`, but you must return `URI`. Moreover, if doing `.queryParam("p", "1+1").build()`, it does **not** encode the plus.

Comment: That is what I'm stating. When using path/variable substition it assumes it needs to do encoding, when you don't do path/variable substition it assumes the value is already encoded. So with `build(value)` you are using path/variable substition, with `build()` you aren't.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see your point. Yes, when you are familiar with the logic of this tool, this behavior seems logical. But when you don't, it does not seem so :) Probably that's just my personal issue, of course. Documentation rules.

Comment: The main difference is the use of variable substition or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum From my researches, some level of encoding is applied even when the query param is not path variable. For example the space character gets encoded always.

Comment: Because you aren't allowed to send spaces in parameters they should be encoded as + (this is part of the spec).